# Github Pages long build time with React

Tags: reactjs, build, github-pages, git-lfs

I am deploying to Github Pages on a `gh-pages` branch and it does so successfully with `npm run deploy`.

However, this repo will eventually contain a LOT of mp3 audio data (I'm using Git LFS) and when I add ~500MB of data to the repo, the build time gets very lonnnnnngg. (15hrs and still running).

While, yes, I know that increasing the size of the build will extend the build time, I didn't think it would take that long.

How long I should expect the build time to go for if I have a 1 GB, 2GB, 5GB size project?

Is there a way to better optimize how I structure my assets? Right now, I have all of my mp3 files in `src/assets` folder

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend keeping your large assets in a separate repository.

```bash
+------------------------------------+       +-----------------------------------+      +-----------------+
|                                    |       |                                   |      |                 |
|   GitHub Repository (gh-pages)     |<----->|   GitHub Repository (assets-repo) |      |       CDN       |
|                                    |       |                                   |      |                 |
|    +------------------------+      |       |    +----------------------+       |      | MP3 Audio Files |
|    |                        |      |       |    |                      |       |      |                 |
|    |   React Project Files  |      |       |    |    MP3 Audio Files   |       |      |                 |
|    |                        |      |       |    |                      |       |      |                 |
|    +------------------------+      |       |    +----------------------+       |      |                 |
|                                    |       |                                   |      |                 |
+------------------------------------+       +-----------------------------------+      +-----------------+
```

Creating a separate repository for storing your MP3 audio files will keep your main project repository lean and should significantly reduce the build times.

```bash
git init assets-repo
cd assets-repo
git lfs track "*.mp3"
git add .gitattributes
git commit -m "Enable Git LFS for MP3 files."
```

You can then use a CDN service like [AWS CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) or [Cloudflare CDN](https://www.cloudflare.com/application-services/products/cdn/) to distribute your audio files.
You would upload your files to the CDN, and the CDN would then distribute them to servers closer to your users, which also improves loading times.

Or use a static file hosting service, like [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/), [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage), or [Azure Blob Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/storage/blobs).

```bash
aws s3 cp /path/to/your/audio/files s3://your-bucket-name --recursive
```

Once your audio files are hosted, you can link to them directly from your main project on GitHub Pages.

```js
// In your React component
const audioSrc = "https://your-cdn-or-hosting-service.com/audio/file1.mp3";
```

---

Note: You can automate the process of uploading new assets to your CDN or static file hosting service using CI/CD pipelines, like [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/actions/checkout) or [Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/).

```yaml
# Example GitHub Actions workflow
name: Upload Audio Assets
on:
    push:
    branches:
        - master
jobs:
    deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
    - name: Upload to S3
        run: |
        aws s3 sync ./audio-files/ s3://your-bucket-name/audio-files/
```